# Twilio - How Generate a key from the main key

Tags: twilio-api, twilio-php

Is it possible to generate a standard key from a "main" key?

I'm trying to generate dynamic keys via api and using it instead of using the account token.

```
           // Generate the key form the main "master" key
           $sid =  "key sid";
           $token = "key secret";
           $twilio = new Twilio($sid, $token);
           $new_key = $twilio->newKeys->create(["friendlyName" => "Some name"]);

           /* For testing */
           echo "<br>This is the new key that was generated - " . $new_key->sid;
           echo "<br>This is the new key secret - " . $new_key->secret;
```

Basically, I'm trying to avoid using the account token to generate keys and hopefully using some sort of master key.

When I try to use the main key for authentication, I get the following error message

```
[HTTP 400] Unable to create record: The request body violates the API contract
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like I figured it out. From what I understand is, that you first have to create a sub account and then created a "Main" token and use that token instead of the root account's token.